# Issue in convert 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<T>' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList<T>>>

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.1 project with this controller action method:

```
[HttpGet("{param1:long}", Name = "GetData")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
public async Task<ActionResult<IReadOnlyList<TestModel>>> GetDataDetails(long param1) => await _testService.GetDetailsAsync(param1);
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Error CS0029
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionResult<System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyList>'

Can anyone help me here by providing some guidance?

Comment: Your action returns an `IReadOnlyList`, but its return type is a generic `ActionResult`. Maybe convert your list to JSON? ([Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.json?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) is MSDN docs for `Controller.Json`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return value expects an ActionResult. Either use `Task<IReadOnlyList<TestModel>>` as the result of the function or try to use one of the provided methods that Wrap your result in an ActionResults like `this.Ok(await _testService.GetDetailsAsync(param1))`

Comment: Thanks @Wolfspirit for your response. I have another action filter which gets executed after the above method and sets up the response with appropriate HTTP Status codes. I wanted to avoid setting up the HTTPStatus codes based on the result in each and every action method and hence thought of implementing the action filter

Comment: Just remove the ActionResult from the response then by replacing `Task<ActionResult<IReadOnlyList<TestModel>>>` with `Task<IReadOnlyList<TestModel>>`

Comment: Thanks @Wolfspirit for your response. It helped me to fix the issue now :)

Comment: @santoshkumarpatro No problem :-) Don't forget to mark it as excepted answer if it solved your problem